# Move shape up on mouse click in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I'm recreating this classic helicopter game:

http://www.play-helicopter-game.com/

I can't figure out what I should be using to recreate the upward motion that occurs when the user holds down the mouse. Does anybody know what I should be using in KineticJS to recreate this effect on a shape?

I considered tween but it seems to only work if you're moving the shape to predetermined coordinates.

Please let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's is some starting code for you to experiment with...**

As you've discovered a Tween will only move something from A to B without much control.

Instead, create an animation loop that changes your helicopter "Y" property each frame

```
var helo;
var heloY=50;
var direction=0;

var animation=new Kinetic.Animation(function(){
    helo.setY(heloY);
    heloY+=direction*1;
},layer);
```

Listen for mousedown events on your helicopter and set the direction to up

```
helo.on("mousedown",function(){direction=-1;});
```

Listen for mouseup and mouseout events on your helicopter and set the direction to down

```
helo.on("mouseleave mouseup",function(){direction=1;});
```